# Wrong resource shown at design time in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio and productFlavors for one of the project. For all variants of product flavors, i am just changing resources (image and layout) and rest of the files are common in main folder.

The problem is that, layout design always shows image of first created product flavor. However, when i run it on device, it shows correct images of respective flavor.

I have tried refreshing layout, rebuild/clean project etc as well as invalidate studio cache multiple times but no results!

Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved by syncing gradle files:

> **Tools** > **Android** > **Sync Project with Gradle Files**

Comment: I've try this with no success. The UI designer still look at the old value which no longer exist on the file. I don't know where it look for the resource. Any other way to tell UI designer to look at the correct resource?

Comment: @Kurotsuki If you're using flavors or build variants the file can have different versions on each flavor or variant. Did you check it?

Comment: I fix it by using menu File --> invalidate cache. It's now showing correct value.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what was the problem, previously i was using Android Studio 2.0 Beta and facing problem in it. But it is resolved after updating Android Studio latest plugin. May be some issue in Android Studio preview.

Thanks